I am running UBUNTU 20.04, and all of a sudden with no warning it freezes to nothing , then my monitor times out for loss of video?
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.
System has been on for 2 or 3 weeks and was working fine, no errors of any kind.
But, suddenly without any warning of any kind, my computer just freezes up.
All operation stops, monitor goes Black, then monitor times out for lack of video.
No keyboard functions work.
Only way to restore is turn power to computer off, then reboot.
What's going on?
